# Crop image on uibezierpath swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an image that I want to crop at an specific shape. So I used this:

```
var aPath = UIBezierPath()
    // Set the starting point of the shape.
    aPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0))
    // Draw the lines.
    aPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(50.0, 0.0))
    aPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(50.0, 50.0))
    aPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(0.0, 50.0))
    aPath.closePath()
    var imgView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "kat.jpg")!)
    imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
    self.view.addSubview(imgView)
```

But it doesn't work. It picks the original image, and resizes it to the height and with of 100px. But I want to crop it inside the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an CAShapeLayer from your path, and the assign this layer to the `mask` property of your image view